# How to reduce the frequency of calls to an API?

Tags: javascript, async-await, suitescript2.0

I am updating a stock items by REST API,
1 first call: get the token

then a loop through an array containing the items and quantity
inside these loops, there are 2 calls (one for the getting  the external system item id and the other for updating the quantities).
My system is netsuite and the external system is lightspeed.

So for my code is for the token call and the loop calls wrap

```
   async function exec(){
    const resFileId = await runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({
      name: "custscript_fileid"
    });
    const resQuery = await runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({
      name: "custscript_lspd_query"
    });
    log.audit("file Id",resFileId);
    log.audit("Query Type",resQuery);
    if(resFileId){
      const csvFile = await file.load({
        id:resFileId
      });
      const data = await readFile(csvFile);
      log.debug("data", data);
      if(resQuery == "updateInventory" && data)
        const token = await lightspeedRefreshTheToken();
        for(let i of data){
          await setTimeout(function(){ log.debug('In Loop','Ran after 1 second'); }, 1000);
          await lightspeedUpdateItemQuantity(token, data[0], data[1]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

the token function

```
async function lightspeedRefreshTheToken(context) {
    await setTimeout(function(){ log.audit('Token Ran after 1 second'); }, 1000);
    var lightspeedStringUrl = lightspeedHost + "/oauth/access_token.php";
    var lightspeedGrantType = "refresh_token";
    var lightspeedData = "client_id=" + lightspeedClientId
    + "&client_secret=" + lightspeedClientSecret
    + "&grant_type=" + lightspeedGrantType
    + "&refresh_token=" + lightspeedRefreshToken;
    var lightspeedHeader = { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" };
    const response = await https
    .post({
      url: lightspeedStringUrl,
      body: lightspeedData,
      headers: lightspeedHeader
    })
    var newSFID = JSON.parse(response.body);
    return newSFID.access_token
  };
```

the details calls function

```
async function lightspeedUpdateItemQuantity(token, item, quantity) {
const lightspeedQuantity = quantity;
await setTimeout(function(){ log.debug('Update Shop Quantity','Ran after 1 second'); }, 1000);
    const lightspeedDetails = await lightspeedIGetItemId(token, item)
    .then(async function (result){
      let lightspeedItemID = result[0];
      let lightspeedItemShopID = result[1];
      await setTimeout(function(){ log.debug('Update Shop Item','Ran after 1 second'); }, 1000);
      const shop = await lightspeedUpdateShopItem(token, lightspeedItemShopID, lightspeedItemID, quantity);
    });
}
```

the pseudo setTimeout function

```
 async function setTimeout(aFunction, milliseconds){
   var date = new Date();
   date.setMilliseconds(date.getMilliseconds() + milliseconds);
   while(new Date() < date){
   }

   return aFunction();
 }
```

despite all delays, the external service is sending a 429 response code. Am I doing something wrong?
nb: there is no setTimeout available in netsuite in serverside scripts.

> {
> httpCode: "429",
> httpMessage: "Too Many Requests",
> message: "Rate Limit Exceeded: Please decrease your request volume. To eliminate this message, keep your request rate below 1 requests per second. Clients that continue to receive this response may have their traffic throttled.",
> errorClass: "RateLimitedException"
> }

Comment: There's some strange things going on in your code: you can't just put `async await` before a timeout... you have to return a promise before `await` will work. But `timeout` doesn't even need `async await`. Just put the code that needs to wait one second inside the timeout function. Also, inside `then()` you don't seem to use the returned response?

Comment: @Kokodoko, I was thinking the same thing at first, but the OP has implemented his own synchronous/blocking version of `setTimeout` that seems to work in this context (async/await is still unnecessary though b/c it does not return a promise).

Comment: @Kokodoko, I am using the `let lightspeedItemID = result[0]`;
      `let lightspeedItemShopID = result[1]` from the returned response

Comment: It still looks unnecessarily complex if the goal is just to wait a millisecond before doing a new request. What if your requests are 5 seconds apart? Do you still get the `too many requests` error? Because then it might be a server problem.

Comment: Who is the caller of exec? Is it being called in a loop? 
Another thing, your implementation of `setTimeOut` method is synchronous, in that it does not return/works with promises, so you can remove *async* from its definition and *await* when you call it.